# firestore not giving updated data and don't make api calls too. need to hard refresh it

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have created a profiles collection with (name, roles and user_id) fields. by default the roles is to "customer".

```
export const createProfile = async (
  first_name,
  last_name,
  display_name,
  uid,
  email
) => {
  try {
    const docRef = await setDoc(doc(db, "profiles", uid), {
      first_name: first_name,
      last_name: last_name,
      display_name: display_name,
      roles: "customer",
      user_id: uid,
      email: email,
    });
    return docRef;
  } catch (error) {
    return
  }
};
```

I have created this createProfile utility function to create profile when user signup with google or with email/password with firebase default authentication feature.And it does create profile and making the profile id as user uid.

And I have create another function to get profile.

```
export const getUserProfile = async (profileId) => {
  try {
    const docRef = doc(db, "profiles", profileId);
    const docSnapshot = await getDoc(docRef);

    if (docSnapshot.exists()) {
      console.log(docSnapshot.data());
      return docSnapshot.data();
    } else {
      console.log("No data Found");
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Something went wrong!");
  }
};
```

this function do fetch the profile when I login as I am calling this function when component mount using useEffect.

```
const Dashboard = () => {

  const {setProfile, user} = useStore()

  const getProfile = async ()=>{
    const response = await getUserProfile(user?.uid);
    setProfile(response)
  }



useEffect(()=>{
  if(user){
      getProfile()
  }
}, [])

  return (
    <>
    //.....)
```

and this does fetch the profile initially when I signup or login. now when I logout.

```
<MenuItem onClick={()=>{signOut(auth), logOut(),  navigate('/signin')}}>Sign out</MenuItem>
```

with the firestore logout function made custom logout function when setProfile state to null. Now when I login again to the same account it didn't show me the update roles. lets say if initially it was customer and in firestore I change it to admin. than hard refresh the browser than it show me the admin and when I logout and log in again than again it show me the same role which is customer.and when I try console.log it didn't make request 2nd time and show the same data which it was before.
what is wrong I am doing.